# how datatype of input parameter of anonymous method determined

Tags: c#, asp.net, anonymous

I am learning ASP.NET core and in the Startup.cs file I see the context object being referred to write the response as shown below:

[image]

I want to know how the input parameter "context" data type is determined?

Please make me understand how the context object is instantiated.

Comment: Paste your code, using pictures is really bad for questions by multiple reasons. No indexing, the people here can't copy the picture and try it out too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Run` method is an extension method for [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder`](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Builder/IApplicationBuilder/) defined in the class [`RunExtensions`](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Builder/RunExtensions/index.html). It has the following signature:

```
Run(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate)
```

This means that it expects a [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate`](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Http/RequestDelegate/index.html#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate) as parameter. Now that delegate is defined as follows:

```
public delegate Task RequestDelegate(HttpContext context);
```

Ergo, your context variable must be of type [`HttpContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.